# how to download files from tfs proxy programatically using C# api

Tags: c#

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("tfs server:8080/tfs/projectcollection name"), ncr);
```

Using above code snippet we can download files from actual `TFS` server, but we need to download files from `TFS` proxy to reduce the load on actual `TFS` server

Answer (score 0):

You must use the default proxy 8081 port!